# Unable to boot past BIOS after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 on my Surface Pro 3. Previously everything had been working fine.

Now, I am not able to get past the BIOS menu when booting up the system.

The installation was done from a USB drive choosing the option to erase the hard drive and do a clean install.

I am still able to boot into the USB stick and "Try Ubuntu without installing", so I can still do some tasks on the computer.

Running the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Yields me the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4879C905-A79A-4E17-867A-41F19BEAA4B6

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2    1050624 483534847 482484224 230.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  483534848 500117503  16582656   7.9G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4022337024 bytes, 7856127 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x40a863e7

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 2955679 2955680  1.4G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       2927216 2931951    4736  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Then the output of the command `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="F1D2-215A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="23fcd6f2-a342-4599-b2b4-0fe13ebac20d"
/dev/sda2: UUID="14fdbfec-15ec-42f1-a314-fe87f0cd5905" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5431fe91-5504-4f4f-86d9-c44f8b5ba060"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda3: UUID="179b5324-513f-4e45-903c-7013c3ff27bf" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="f0bf4688-a7a8-4434-abbc-600d8447a82a"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2016-07-19-21-27-51-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="40a863e7" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="40a863e7-01"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="0F7B-9366" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="40a863e7-02"
```

Not knowing that much about computers in general, it looks to me as if I do have the operating system on my disk.

Furthermore, I am not able to access GRUB by holding SHIFT when starting, neither through spamming ESC. I just get into the BIOS menu. How do I actually boot into Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the mode u installed your ubuntu in your laptop. If u installed it in UEFI mode and Your system default boot mode is UEFI then ubuntu will boot else it won't.Similar is the case with LEGACY mode if u installed it in legacy it won't boot in UEFI mode.U can go into the BIOS menu (search the key on Google.generally it is F11 F12 F10 or F2) and check the BOOT options. Whichever mode it is already set (UEFI OR LEGACY) change it (if legacy then uefi and v.v).now save and exit BIOS menu.If u really installed Ubuntu properly then It will boot.